# Group by sets of values in a column in sql / hiveql

Tags: hiveql

I have a table with number of trips and day of week (Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday.....) I would like to aggregate the number of trips by 'weekend' and 'weekday'. Is there a way I can group Sunday and Saturday to fall under weekend and the remaining under weekday?

Comment: Are you using Oracle or Hiveql? Please keep proper tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, extending from @stickybit's answer, if you have a date column available you can get the day of the week using `TO_CHAR`:

```
   .
   .
   .
GROUP BY CASE 
           WHEN TRIM(TO_CHAR(YOUR_DATE_FIELD, 'DAY')) IN ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY') THEN
             'WEEKEND'
           ELSE
             'WEEKDAY'
         END;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0f358/3)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CASE ... END` to map Saturday and Sunday to another value e.g. Weekend and else use the weekday.

```
...
GROUP BY CASE
           WHEN weekday IN ('Saturday',
                            'Sunday') THEN
             'Weekend'
           ELSE
             weekday
         END
```

(`weekday` being the column, that stores the weekday.)

Edit:

Or, if you want Monday to Friday as Weekday, not by their individual names (I'm not sure how to understand your post at second glance.):

```
...
GROUP BY CASE
           WHEN weekday IN ('Saturday',
                            'Sunday') THEN
             'Weekend'
           ELSE
             'Weekday'
         END
```